# problema con operadores en c++

Tags: c++

Tengo un problema con `C++`, deseo calcular el descuento de un pago que calculé (pago) con un 20% si el monto supera los 20000, pero el programa no calcula correctamente el monto.

Ejemplo: Horas = 50, tarifa = 1000

El pago debe ser las primeras 35 horas a la tarifa fijada y el resto a 1.5 de la tarifa, esos cálculos los tengo bien porque los pido por pantalla y esta correctos, el problema es al aplicar el descuento por ser un monto mayor a 20000, donde "pago = pago1 - pago1*0.2", el valor del ejemplo debería dar 46000 y no me da eso.

CODIGO

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std; 

int main(){
    float tarifa, pago1, pago, n2, n1, n;
    int horas;

    cout<<"Ingrese tarifa fija: ";  
    cin>>tarifa;    
    cout<<"Ingrese horas: ";    
    cin>>horas; 

    if(horas > 35){ 
        n1 = 35 * tarifa;
        n2 = (horas-35)*tarifa*1.5; 
        pago1 = n1 + n2; 
    }    
    else{
        n = tarifa*horas;   
    }

    if(n < 20000){
        pago = n;   
    }
    else{
        pago = pago1*(1-0.2);   
    }

    cout<<"El pago mensual del obrero es: "<<pago;  

    return 0; 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

el problema que veo es que ocupas 2 variables distintas para determinar, digamoslo así, el pago inicial. Si son mas de 35 horas, el resultado lo dejas en la variable `pago1`, pero sino, lo dejas en la variable `n`.

la corrección puede ser entonces, definiendo solo una variable, por ejemplo `pago1`, con lo que el código quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    float tarifa, pago1, pago, n2, n1, n;
    int horas;
    cout<<"Ingrese tarifa fija: ";
    cin>>tarifa;
    cout<<"Ingrese horas: ";
    cin>>horas;
    if(horas > 35){

        n1 = 35 * tarifa;
        n2 = (horas-35)*tarifa*1.5;
        pago1 = n1 + n2;
    }
    else{
        //n = tarifa*horas;   // unificamos la variable
        pago1 = tarifa*horas;
    }

    // if(n < 20000){   // cambiamos aca
    if(pago1 < 20000){
        // pago = n;   // cambiamos aca
        pago = pago1;
    }
    else{
        pago = pago1*(1-0.2);
    }

    cout<<"El pago mensual del obrero es: "<<pago;

    return 0;

}
```

espero te sirva.